# Поиск после определенного текста/слова Python регулярки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

```
<svg aria-label="Оценить" class="jrei_5 " fill ="#262626" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 48 48" width="24">
```

Таких блоков в html странице несколько, отличается только.

> aria-label="текст"

Мне нужно найти текст в двух блоках разметки, после текстов "Оценить" и "Поделиться", после этих слов мне нужно найти

> fill ="#262626"

А именно то, что внутри скобок.

```
(Оценить.*?)(#...)
```

Этот код не обнаруживает нужный элемент.

Важное примечание: нужен не весь текст после заданного слова, а именно производить поиск в диапазоне после заданного слова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aria-label="Оценить".*fill\s?="(#\d+)"
```

я бы попробовал что-то такое.
Забирать значение из группы1
[пример](https://regex101.com/r/P4XJcF/1)
елси еще и поделиться, то можно так:

```
aria-label="(Оценить)?|(Поделиться)?".*fill\s?="(#\d+)"
```

тогда забирать из группы3
[пример](https://regex101.com/r/eYHQGA/1)